# Strange issue with mysql index cardiality

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am facing a weird issue when trying to understand (explain) a query.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `trk_track` (
 `track_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `track_date` date NOT NULL,
 `track_hour` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `track_createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `action_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `url_utm_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`track_id`),
 KEY `track_date` (`track_date`,`track_hour`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `action_id` (`action_id`),
 KEY `url_utm_id` (`url_utm_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=284538 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

There are about 200k lines in this table.

But something is very confusing:

1-) First the **cardiality of url_utm_id** index should be **200**, but it shows **'3'** and after **analyze table** it shows **'493**', which is still wrong;

2-) When I try to run this query:

```
explain select count(track_id) from trk_track where url_utm_id in(185);
```

it shows:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  trk_track   NULL    ref     url_utm_id  url_utm_id  5   const   53  100.00  Using index
```

It is ok because there are only **53 url_utm_id(185)** in trk_track.

But if I try to do:

```
explain select count(track_id) from trk_track where url_utm_id in(select url_utm_id from trk_url_utm where utm_id=102);
```

it shows:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  trk_url_utm     NULL    ref     PRIMARY,utm_id  utm_id  4   const   1   100.00  Using index
1   SIMPLE  trk_track   NULL    ref     url_utm_id  url_utm_id  5   db_trk.trk_url_utm.url_utm_id   577     100.00  Using index
```

**This subquery:**

```
select url_utm_id from trk_url_utm where utm_id=102
```

will return same **'185' ID**

But anyway it sounds like that it tries to make a join, look in explain and it **scan 577 rows**, it doesnt' make sense for me.

It should **scan 53** also, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `cardiality` in index of innodb table is  An estimate of the number of unique values in the index, MySQL Doc shows the details of it : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html

Change the `innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages` may get more accurate values, and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-statistics-estimation.html may help you.

2) `rows` in explain shows the the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query, it's also a approximation. So the value only means MySQL believes is **should examine 577 rows**, not examine 577 rows exactly.

Comment: thank you, i changed this parameter to 20 then i tried again the query and it show the correct examined rows, very cool. :)